# delete attribute CSS DOM JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know what is wrong in my code.
I'd like to delete all "link" tags if there is within the attribute "rel = "stylesheet"

This is my HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>teset</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="test." />
<meta name="author" content="Me" />
<link rel="author" href="www.mysite.uk" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="www.mysite.uk/css/style.css  />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="www.mysite.uk/css/style2.css />
</head>
<script src = "deleteCSS.js"></script>
<body onload="noCSS()">
<p> test !!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my JS called "deleteCSS.js"

```
function noCSS(){ 
//I save tag "link"
var CSSlink = document.getElementsByTagName("link"); 
var CSSatt = CSSlink.getAttribute("rel");

for (i=0; i < CSSlink.length; i++){  
if (CSSatt[i] == "stylesheet"){
CSSlink[i].remove(); }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function noCSS() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("link");

    for (var i = links.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (links[i].rel === "stylesheet") {
            links[i].parentNode.removeChild(links[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

1. You have to check the `rel` attribute of each `<link>` in the loop;
2. You can remove them in a reversed order (when you remove `links[0]`, `links[1]` takes the place of it and when you remove `links[1]` it actually removes the second one of the rest;
3. Or you can just use `while (links.length)` instead, and always remove `links[0]` (the first one of the rest).

Comment: thank you !!! so how can it understand that links[i].rel (rel) it's an attribute? What is the difference between "==" and "==="? when you write links[i].parentNode.removeChild(links[i]) are you saying that it starts from the parent node of links[i]and then remove the child that contains the rel attribute?

Comment: @user3025314 `links[i].rel` is equivalent to `links[i].getAttribute("rel")`, which means to get the `rel` attribute of the element. To, the second question, try to print the result of `1 == "1"` and `1 === "1"`.

Comment: @user3025314 `links[i].parentNode.removeChild(links[i])` is a way to remove the `links[i]` element from DOM tree.

Answer (score 4):

with jquery try this

```
$("link[rel='stylesheet']").remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Fcxx/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure JavaScript implementation:

```
(function() {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
  for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
    links[i].getAttribute('rel') === 'stylesheet' && links[i].remove();
  }
})();
```

Copy this to a file `no-css.js` and put it at the end of your HTML file.

Your code is not working because `getElementsByTagName` is returning a `NodeList`, so calling `getAttribute('rel')` of it will return an error `TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'getAttribute'`. So you have to iterate through all the links (nodes) and if they have the `rel` attribute set to `stylesheet`, remove them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The 4th line should be `links[i].getAttribute('rel') === 'stylesheet' && links[i--].remove();`?

Answer (score 0):

This is another JavaScript implementation:

```
    function noCSS(){ 

        var CSSlink = document.getElementsByTagName("link"); 

        for (i=0; i < CSSlink.length; i++ )
        { 
            if (CSSlink[i].getAttribute("rel") === "stylesheet")
            {
                CSSlink[i--].remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

Make sure you enter the quotation marks at the end of the `href` tags like
`href="www.mysite.uk/css/style.css"`